# Doctrine2 repository, Many-to-Many associations and Twig templates: best practices

Tags: php, symfony, many-to-many, doctrine-orm, twig

I have following question:

Imagine that we have an entity, e.g. *Event*.

In *EventRepository* class I've added some methods for querying some kind of Events.

In the *EventController* I've got a collection of Events. Last step - display all these Events in the template. Basically there is nothing difficult:

```
{% for event in events %}...{% endfor %}
```

**But I have one additional condition**: I need to display Users who goes to the each Event (e.g. 10 users for each). Event linked to the User with Many-to-Many association. Ok, I've added method to the EventRepository to find event participants. But I have no access to the EventRepository in Twig template... :(

I see three options:

1. (quick and tricky) Get participants directly by the Entity: `{% for event in events %}{% set participants = event.participants %}{% endfor %}`. This works, but when we'll have participants count 1000+? Afaik event->getParticipants() will querying all 1000+ Users at once that will break my page.
2. pass EventRepository instance into temlpate and query 10 users for each event, something like this: `{% for event in events %}{% set participants = eventRepository.getEventParticipants(event.id, max) %}{% endfor %}`. This looks more correct but looks like this breaks core MVC concepts - querying database within templates.
3. Loop events in the controller and prepare Participants list for each. Look ugly (at least dooble loop for events and more code in controller), but more or less right (and what need to do when new conditions appears?).

Can you take any advise for this case? How I need to query N-N relation and where in my code?

Answer (score 1):

As long as your relationships are correctly set on your Event entity you should be able to lazy load the users when they're required. So for example when iterating over your events you should be able to call..

```
$event->getUsers();
```

Doctrine2 is really well suited for these exact types of operations (lazy loading the content when its required).

Make sure you have a valid relation between Events and Users and write a getter in your Events entity to pull out all users as either an array, or using Doctrine's ArrayCollection class.

Comment: I have valid relation. And I using now event.participants ($event->getParticipants()) as you suggested. But **I can't limit selection**. I need only 5-10 users. But Event can have 1000+ participants. I don't need them all in this case.

Comment: If your using the ArrayCollection object then you have filtering options available to you. If not then you could either pass a parameter to limit the results, or create a separate method for this case.

Comment: How I can filter ArrayCollection (looks like filtering also will loop arround all related participants)? I have generated getter in Event entity: it simply return `$this->participants` (all participants I mean!). Good point - to use `EventRepository::getParticipants($eventId, $max)` but i can't use it in the template (violates by core MVC concepts in my opinion)

Comment: I believe ArrayCollection has a filter method that allows you to pass a Closure.

Comment: You should take a look at [extra lazy associations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html). I've never tried, but I think you could write `event.participants.slice(0, 10);` and if the association is extra lazy offset and limit parts will be added to the query automatically.

Comment: @1ed Oh! This looks interesting ) I'll try it.